# Adding a LongClick to a Database ListView Android

Tags: android, database, long-click

I have been trying to implement a LongClick on my database for quite some time, but for now it is only a short click that works. I'm writing in android an I have a database that I am trying to delete records from. Here's my code so far,

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //THIS IS TO DELETE FROM DATABASE, NEED TO IMPLEMENT LONGCLICK
    Vehicle toDelete = ((ArrayAdapter<Vehicle>) l.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
    VehicleDataSource vds = new VehicleDataSource(this);
    vds.deleteVehicle(toDelete);
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```

}

Heres my delete vehicle method in my VehicleDataSource class,

```
  public synchronized void deleteVehicle(Vehicle v) throws SQLException {
      SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_VEHICLE, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {v.getId() + ""});
  }
```

If anyone could give me any tips or any help that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set an [OnItemLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) on your [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29), then handle interactions with the selected view in your on `boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method.  It might be worth checking out the documentation on [handling input events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).